# C# Powershell script failing: "failed to get zone information"

Tags: c#, powershell, dns, windows-server-2012

I've created a small site which pragmatically creates DNS NS records. When I execute my code in PS (on my site.com server) it works perfectly, but when I run it from the website (hosted on my site.com server) it fails with the error: "Error creating IP 1.1.1.1. Error: Failed to get the zone information for site.com on server myServer"

My PS script is:

```
Add-DnsServerZoneDelegation site.com –childzonename lab00012 –IPAddress 1.1.1.1 –nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

My C# code is:

```
var labString = "lab" + tenantString;
var scriptText = "Add-DnsServerZoneDelegation site.com –childzonename " + labString
            + " –IPAddress " + ipAddress + " –nameserver " + ipAddress;
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
    var results = pipeline.Invoke();;
}
```

I've confirmed that the site will run PS commands such as

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Namespace 'root\\CIMV2' -computername .
```

without an issue.

Powershell version is 3.0, server is Windows Server 2012 running IIS 6.2.

Any help is greately appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your code executing as under IIS? What permissions there are different than your Powershell console?

Comment: I don't know, I assume whatever the defaults are. This is only my second time using IIS so all I did was create a website and push up the files. Sorry, IIS and powershell are pretty new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Power Shell needed enhanced permissions to make changes to DNS (and associated folders and files). After some research I ended up using this code:

```
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$pw= convertto-securestring 'adminPassword' -asplaintext –force");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$user = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential('machine\\Administrator', $pw)");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential $user -ScriptBlock {"+scriptText+"}");
```

I recognize that hard coding my admin password is bad form, but time was running out and I was unable to find a better solution.

If anyone else has a better solution, I am open to it.